# flutter: how to use Cupertino (iOS-style) widgets in windows android studio?

Tags: flutter

I'm new in flutter. The app style is designed for iOS, I notice there are Cupertino widgets and .yaml file has the dependency. My question is how can I adjust these widgets, for dialogue example, can I adjust its height or width or its background color? My question rose because I did have the demand but I haven't found related properties. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use everything without any problems, those widgets are just part of Flutter, nothing more (provided you code and implement it correctly). Doesn't matter what kind of computer you have, while it can run emulator and Android Studio (for example). I mean.. it doesn't bother you that you develop Android apps with Windows PC, right?

Note though, that if you would like to COMPILE your Flutter app for iOS devices (to publish to Apple App Store), only then you would need a Mac.

Comment: thanks for your helpful answer very much. Can I bother to ask about how to adjust the property of the dialogue, such as the background color of it?

Comment: You're welcome! For particular properties of each widget you have to check them out individually to see what they have. In Android Studio you can press ctrl+space inside a widget to see some of them or just check the docs at https://api.flutter.dev/